# Open Layers with Google Maps in OpenGTS

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I am using Open Layers as my OpenGTS map service provider by default.
I am now working on adding Google Maps as one of the base layers for Open Layers.
I modified the OpenLayers.js by changing the "MAPQUEST_showOSMLayer" to following:

```
/* Mapquest OSM */
if (MAPQUEST_showOSMLayer) 
{
    this.openLayersMap.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Street"));
    baseLayerCount++;
}
```

But when i load the map, this error message appeared:

```
[jsMapInit]:openLayers
Error Initializing map
(map provided service maybe temporary unavailable)
ReferenceError:google is not defined
```

I guess it was because I didn't put in the google maps api js.
Where should I put in then?
Or how should I correct it?
Any help? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, looks like the error does not come from this piece of code. Could you provide it all please?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
It's definitely not come from the code. And the openlayers.js is more than 2000 rows of coding.
Perhaps you will want to refer to the OpenGTS Project?
[link](http://opengts.org)

Comment: No I mean, could you provide your FILENAME.js (or FILENAME.html, FILENAME.ASP, ... ) code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way.
Add in the missing google api js file in the "OpenLayers.java."
Go to near line 180, change to the following:

```
super.writeJSIncludes(out, reqState, new String[] {
JavaScriptTools.qualifyJSFileRef("maps/jsmap.js"),
(!StringTools.isBlank(jsURL)? jsURL : OPENLAYERS_JS_URL),
JavaScriptTools.qualifyJSFileRef("maps/OpenLayers.js"),
JavaScriptTools.qualifyJSFileRef("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false")
});
```

Then recompile, rebuild your project. That's it!